# JqxTree is taking time to load with 500 records

Tags: jquery, performance, jqwidget, jqxtree

It is taking around 3-4 seconds to load 500 records which is very slow as it is hampering my app performance.

```
var source = {
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [
        { name: "Rid", type: "int" },
        { name: "ParentRid", type: "int" },
        { name: "Name", type: "string" },
        { name: "Text", type: "string" }
    ],
    id: "Rid",
    localdata: dataSource,
    async: false, 
    hasThreeStates: false
};

var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
dataAdapter.dataBind();

var records = dataAdapter.getRecordsHierarchy("Rid", "ParentRid", "items", [{ name: "Text", map: "label" }, { name: "Rid", map: "value" }, { name: "Name", map: "Name" }]);

$("#jqxtree").jqxTree({ checkboxes: true, source: records, width: '100%', height: 220 });
```

I want to load 'JqxTree' control in such a way that other things won't wait for it to load.
Is there any way in the jQuery to load 'JqxTree' control in the background?

Or something we can do which won't affect performance of whole application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/ai/search/35255

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77948229/jqxtree-is-loading-slow-with-500-records